# Requirements for a custom android View

Tags: android, view, xamarin

I'm interested in using a custom View to draw, measure, and display a set of buttons that is dependent on a back-end for my application. This requires me to implement this in Android dynamically. Would you help me get started?

Here we go: first in my `MainActivity` I instantiate my custom class which inherits from `TableLayout` which is also a view:

```
var keyboardView = new KeyboardView(this, layout, droidLayout, this.Colors);
```

Then I set the content view to the fresh instance of my custom class: `SetContentView(keyboardView);` Here's my class's constructor which just helps me get scope on all of the info I need:

```
public KeyboardView(Context context, KeyboardLayout layout, int droidLayout, Dictionary<string, int> colors)
    : base(context) {
    this._Colors = colors;
    this._Context = context;
    this.KeyboardLayout = layout;
    this.SetWillNotDraw(false);
    //this.ButtonLayout = ll;
    this.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
    this.DroidLayout = droidLayout;
```

I've also overridden both `OnMeasure` and `OnDraw`:

```
protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int h = 100;
    int w = 100;
    //Overall keyboard/View dimensions //Difference between Canvas size and KeyboardDimensions?
    this.SetMeasuredDimension(w, h);

    //this.Layout.CanvasSize.
}

protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    var bt = new Button(this._Context);
    bt.Text = "laaaa";
    this.AddView(bt);
}
```

Now what's happening is that `OnDraw` and `OnMeasure` both get it, in fact, `OnDraw` seems to be getting hit lots of time -- more so then I wish to count. However, the one button that I added via `AddView` is NOT drawn on the screen. If you guys could help me get this one button on the screen I can get to writing the core logic!

On a side-note: I can draw stuff on my screen if I set an `XML layout` file as the view as such: `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LayoutName)` But, since the nature of my program requires dynamic views being added all the time, I'd rather avoid writing lengthy Layout files. Thanks guys! Bump my question up if you think it's a worthwhile one!

Comment: Hey! Let me know WHY you downvote my question please. This will allow me to ask more intelligent questions later on!

Answer (score 1):

In general, [this](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) is a good place to start.  In particular it details how to add custom attributes, how to perform custom drawing, and how to design custom events that make sense in the context of your own application.

Also, it looks like you're trying to use C# style syntax in Java, which won't work for things like inheritance.  Reading some java tutorials might help you out. 
[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) is a good resource for that and should help you get up and going. Good luck!

Comment: Good link. If you'll notice, I tagged xamarin in my post. This allows me to use c# code in android!

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to call the super() to allow the parent class to do what it needs to do for the overridden method.

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super(canvas)
}
```

Related link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound

Comment: I tried using the c# equivelant but it isn't correct: `protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas) : base(canvas) { }`